# Possible to abort mid-task on error?

Tags: ansible

Given a task that performs a service restart on five different hosts, is it possible to tell ansible that if the restart fails on host1, to abort the entire run without doing the restart on hosts 2-5?

The `any_errors_fatal` setting combined with `--forks=1` and `serial: 1` settings all seem promising but don't seem to it.

```
- hosts: all
  serial: 1
  any_errors_fatal: true
  become: yes
  roles:
    - service_control
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try setting `max_fail_percentage` to zero? From [Maximum Failure Percentage](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_delegation.html#maximum-failure-percentage)

```
- hosts: all
  serial: 1
  max_fail_percentage: 0
  become: yes
  roles:
    - service_control
```